# dask-ec2 keyname does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, dask

I'm trying to use dask-ec2 to set up an EC2 cluster on AWS, but ran into some trouble trying when trying the 'dask-ec2 up' command.  The error I get is:

```
ERROR: The keyname 'my_keyname_here' does not exist, please create it in the EC2 console
```

(I've replaced my actual keyname with 'my_keyname_here', so this is not the problem)

However, when I try the following, my key name is found:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name='eu-west-1')
print(client.describe_key_pairs(KeyNames=['my_keyname_here']))
```

Based on the source code on GitHub (https://github.com/dask/dask-ec2), this is exactly what dask-ec2 tries to do when this error occurs. I'm also able to find my key name using the AWS CLI.

I'm using Anaconda with python 3.5.2 on a Windows 10 machine.

Does anyone know what may cause this issue?

Comment: have you setup the region with dask?

Comment: I've set the region in the configuration file for AWS cli

Comment: @PeterSandberg is setting the region in the config file for the AWS cli sufficient to set the region for the dask-ec2 tool?  Perhaps try setting the region there as well.  `dask-ec2 --help` may be of use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that dask-ec2 does not read the region from the AWS CLI. If you want to use another region than the default (us-east-1) you need to specify it using the '--region-name' flag when running 'dask-ec2 up':

```
dask-ec2 up --keyname my_keyname_here --keypair /path/to/my/keypair --region-name eu-west-1
```